# Windows Live Writer Cannot Connect to Blog Service in a Windows Azure Website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, windows-live-writer

I have both [MiniBlog](https://github.com/madskristensen/miniblog) and [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) running in my Azure Websites account. In both cases, Windows Live Writer is not able to connect.

### What have I tried?

- **MiniBlog remote posting address** http://bigfont-miniblog.azurewebsites.net/metaweblog
- **Navigation works from a web browser:**

[image: Browser Navigation]

- **Navigation fails from Live Writer:**

[image: Live Writer Error]

Since this is working neither for Orchard CMS nor MiniBlog, I am wondering whether it has something to do with Azure security. How do I connect Windows Live Writer to a blog that's running in a Windows Azure Website?

Comment: You can use Fiddler to see if you can get more insight into the actual error. You have to change the filter in Fiddler to 'Any Process' or target the Live Writer process to see the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I had manually configured a Web Proxy during a previous trouble shooting session. When I **unchecked** the Manually configure settings box, Live Writer again worked.

**Open Set Proxy...**

[image]

**Un-check This Box**

[image]